# How to get all the rows of a table, not just the first row?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Good afternoon community! I need help writing a parser, I'm just starting to program in Python 3, maybe I'm missing something. The task is this:
The site has a table with football teams, using Requests and BeautifulSoup I was able to get the source code of this table into the firsttable variable, the print command normally displays all the data I need, but when I try to display it in a list of the form:

```
10:00 Team 1 Team 2
11:00 Team 3 Team 4
12:00 Team 5 Team 6
```

And so on, I can only get the first value from the list, I tried to use the While loop (for example, While i <10), it repeats to me the first value from the table 10 times, but does not pars the remaining ones. What am I doing wrong?

```
def get_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    firsttable = soup.findAll('table', class_='predictionsTable')[0]
    print(firsttable) #Here, all the data that I need is displayed in the console as html source

    for scrape in firsttable:

        try:
            hometeam = scrape.find('td', class_='COL-3').text
        except:
            hometeam = 'Hometeam Error'

        try:
            awayteam = scrape.find('td', class_='COL-5').text
        except:
            awayteam = 'Away Team Error'

        try:
            btts = scrape.find('td', class_='COL-10').text
        except:
            btts = 'BTTS Score Error'

        datenow = str(datetime.date.today())

        print(datenow,hometeam,awayteam,btts)
```

Comment: Can you include the URL

Comment: Yes, sure. https://www.over25tips.com/both-teams-to-score-tips/ in this site i need to take only first talbe with header "Btts predictions for today"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop `for scrape in firsttable` only has one iteration, of the entire table content, which is why you are finding only the first row. Instead of using a loop I would recommend the `find_all` method. This worked for me:

```
url = 'https://www.over25tips.com/both-teams-to-score-tips/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'lxml')

firsttable = soup.findAll('table', class_='predictionsTable')[0]
hometeams = [x.text for x in firsttable.find_all('td', {'class': 'COL-3 right-align'})]
awayteams = [x.text for x in firsttable.find_all('td', {'class': 'COL-5 left-align'})]
btts = [x.text for x in firsttable.find_all('td', {'class': 'COL-10 hide-on-small-only'})]
datenow = str(datetime.date.today())

for i in range(len(hometeams)):
    print(datenow, hometeams[i], awayteams[i], btts[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to BeautifulSoup's constructor is String.
It is a type of parser.
You want to parse a html, thus you should type 'html.parser' in second argument.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml') => soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I agree.
I will add content to the answer